# Is there such a thing as an Azure Function Reminder Trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, reminders

I would like to write a reminder type system using azure functions. My plan is to create a function with a http trigger which creates the reminder and then a second which would send an email when that reminder is due.

I've looked into timers and I don't believe they will do what I'm after, likewise with queues.

Is there a built in timer which will activate a function at a configurable time (in X hours or at Y:00pm) or should I fall back to my plan to create a timer function which will poll the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach to this problem was to use Service Bus messages. Every time you schedule a reminder, send a message to your queue with [`ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet) property set to the time you want (absolute date/time).

Make an Azure Function which will be triggered by this Service Bus queue. Function will get called soon after that date/time, so you can send the reminder at that point.

Comment: In additional, using a method ScheduleMessageAsync allows to cancel a message based on its sequence number and "re-schedule" a new message.

Comment: @mikhail so in this example, if I have a web service running that needs to handle the message, is the purpose of the Function to remove the need of polling the service bus? In other words, when a message is ready, it will be sent to the function that can then determine the right endpoint to post within my webservice. Would that be a good approach? Removing any need for polling

Comment: @EK_AllDay Sounds good to me. You won't be doing any polling yourself indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Workflow that could be created with Azure Durable Functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview).

1. When receiving the HTTP trigger, create a new Workflow with the DurableOrchestrationClient.StartNewAsync method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-instance-management)
2. In your Workflow create a new Timer at the time at which you need the reminder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-timers)
3. In your Workflow create a task to wait on a ReminderCancel event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-external-events). Note: You can raise the ReminderCancel event from any other Function triggered (HTTP trigger, Queue trigger...)
4. In your Workflow wait for both the Cancel event and the Timer elapsed tasks.
5. In your Workflow take action on the first task to trigger by starting an Activity with CallActivityAsync (https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext.html)

Answer (score -1):

While old and boring, a SQL Table will work just fine.

The Reminder Function can auto trigger ~5 min and send/mark the pending reminders.